# What field type should be used for passwords in MySQL when using PHP crypt()

Tags: php, mysql, crypt

Using PHP crypt() method I have a PHP script to store users encrypted passwords in MySQL database. What field type should I use to store the encrypted data?

Comment: Text is fit for the encrypted storage on mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`varchar(`of sufficient length`)`

Comment: Hi wallyk, thanks for reply but I saw a video on Youtube mentioned we can select MD5 data type for md5(). isn't any qual for crypt() type?

Comment: Please, no, **DO NOT** use MD5.

Comment: @tadman , I am not going to use MD5 just curious if there is any associated type for crypt()?

Comment: @MonaCoder:  I don't see any MD5 data type in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-type-overview.html).  Where is it?

Comment: @wallyk A cryptographic hash is not the same as a datatype. In most cases `VARCHAR` is how these are stored.

Comment: I saw it at this video tutorial from PHP academy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVZqxoesuko

Comment: @tadman:  Yes, I know.  I was asking about Mona's comment (the first one) which says *MD5 data type*.

Comment: @MonaCoder Be very careful with tutorials that describe how to make a login system. Most are incomplete and/or hazardous to use in a production environment. If you're not using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that comes with a built-in authentication system, like [Laravel does](http://laravel.com/docs/security), then be sure to observe [all the best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) when it comes to security. A "hex digest" of a hash can be stored in any string-like field (e.g. `VARCHAR`).

Comment: MD5 __isn't__ a [datatype in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use 'varchar'

In additon to wallyk's answer,
Exact lengths of encrytpted strings using crypt() are;

```
Standard DES: stqAdD7zlbByI
Extended DES: _S4..someQXidlBpTUu6
MD5: $1$somethin$4NZKrUlY6r7K7.rdEOZ0w.
Blowfish: $2a$09$anexamplestringforsaleLouKejcjRlExmf1671qw3Khl49R3dfu
SHA-256: $5$rounds=5000$anexamplestringf$KIrctqsxo2wrPg5Ag/hs4jTi4PmoNKQUGWFXlVy9vu9
SHA-512: $6$rounds=5000$anexamplestringf$Oo0skOAdUFXkQxJpwzO05wgRHG0dhuaPBaOU/
         oNbGpCEKlf/7oVM5wn6AN0w2vwUgA0O24oLzGQpp1XKI6LLQ0.
```

Comment: Please [do not link to w3schools](http://w3fools.com/). It causes a ton of damage.

Comment: w3schools causes damage? new here so please explain

Comment: It's full of dangerously inaccurate information and encourages recklessly bad habits. The link I posted explains more. Thanks for updating your answer.

Comment: will read later, thanks for making me aware, original answer edited.

Comment: If you're using md5 for "recent projects", [you're doing it wrong](http://lemonodor.com/images/mccarthy-youre-doing-it-wrong-s.jpg)

Comment: I felt this was pretty strong, i always saw it as, to crack this you need to knwo the password originally. Please guide me on this encryptions short comings

Comment: Do some simple searching. md5 has been considered insecure for a number of years now. That's not really the topic of the original question though. (but for quick reference, there's [this](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash)

Comment: will definately be looking into this further. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of encryption you are using but varbinary is appropriate in some situations.